# Pyjnius + Sikuli + MacOS: hangs when we try to create object of Screen class

Tags: sikuli, pyjnius

On MacOS Monterey
open the python3.9 in shell with pyjnius libary installed and sikuliapi 2.0.5 library jar added to CLASSPATH.

```py
from jnius import autoclass  # works fine
Screen = autoclass('org.sikuli.script.Screen')  # works fine
screen = Screen()  # get stuck here with no error.
```

This works perfectly fine in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, tried with 2.0.6-snapshot on a Mac M2.

- Python 3.10 with pyjnius installed
- CLASSPATH=..../sikulixide-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT-complete-macm.jar

In Python prompt:

- Made Screen, Region and Image ready using autoclass()

This worked:

```
 print(Screen().toString())
```

gives: `R[0,0 1470x956]@S(0)`

```py
image = Image(Screen().capture(0, 0, 40, 40))
match = Screen().find(image)
print(match.toString())
```

gives: `M[0,0 40x40]IN(0) %100,00 C(20,20) [602/602 msec]`

So the basic features are working.

Features that try to display a Java Frame or Dialog (Region.highlight, Screen.userCapture, SX.popup, ...) do not work and do not come back.

Conclusion: It principally works, but some features do not work.

I do not have a working Python 3 on Windows available, but I am sure, that the same would have happened on Windows.

RaiMan from SikuliX